# Finding the volume formed by rotating $y=x(1-x)$ about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, volume, rotations

In my calculus book, there was a problem as follows.

Find the volume formed by rotating the region $R$, where $R$ is defined as the region enclosed by the function $y=x(1-x)$ and the  $y$-axis.

This was straightforward ($V=\frac{\pi}{6}$ units$^2$ by using the "shell" method) until I asked myself:

> what about rotating this region about the $x$-axis?

I cannot figure out the volume formed with such a rotation.

Comment: This is the first volume calculation you met, $\int_0^1 \pi x^2(1-x)^2\,dx$. Expand and integrate.

Comment: Was completely overthinking that, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.